# How to secure ElmahCore Errprs Dashboard page on ASP.NET CORE API end

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, elmah

I have ASP.NET Core API that is being consumed by an Angular app. Now I have implemented ElmahCore error logging API that shows all errors of Backend API on the URL:

[www.myAPI.com/elmah](http://www.myAPI.com/elmah)

This URL is currently public so what are my options to secure it so that only logged in user could access it. Currently angular app has implementation of JWT token to access some secure api endpoints. But since its not API end point, but a web page provided by elmah on the API, I dont know how to secure it.

Comment: You can [add `Authorize` in your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm8Lu.png). [Does this article useful to you ?](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-net-5-0/)

Comment: Or you can create a method, if the jwt is valid, you can redirect to this url.

Comment: I already have JWT token authentication implemented that will protect all my created API endpoints returning data. But in this particular case, elmah has created a URL that shows all errors. Now If I had an action method in some controller that returned this page, I could simply add [Authrorize] attribute to protect it. But since this URL and page is generated by Elmah API, I cant do that. Hope it clears my problem